# Qt Serial Read data missing

Tags: qt, qt5

Qt is unable to read all data coming through COM port. I use baud rate 4800. Some data goes missing. Why is that.  If I send 20 lines,  like I receive only 15/16.

Here is the code:

```
  if (arduino - > canReadLine()) 
{
QByteArray serialData = arduino->readLine () ;
QString serialBuffer = QString :: fromStdString(SerialData.toStdString());
ui->listWidget->addItem(serialBuffer) ;
}
```

My listWidget displays only a few incoming data, rest is lost.

```
Qt Serial Port Settings :
Baud Rate = 4800
Data Bits = Data8
Flow Control  = NoFlowControl 
Parity = NoParity 
Stop Bits = OneStop 


Arduino (Transmitter) baud rate = 4800
```

.

Comment: Please put some code with your COM parameters. And add the COM parameters of the device you're reading from.

Comment: my code is shown below

Comment: Use `QString serialBuffer = serialData;` Do not pass it via std::string.

Comment: still the same. some data go missing

Comment: Both transmission and reception are at the same baud rates. Why then does the data get lost?  If I use readAll()  instead of readLine (),  I receive all data, but the are mis aligned, i e broken lines appear.

Comment: What's in the incoming data ? Is it a single line ? Don't you have a loop somewhere ?

Comment: Data is food name &  quantity. I have a loop to check the incoming data and store in sqlite database for each incoming data.

Comment: @KrishnajithSS you don't tell if it's one line or two (or more), and you don't  show the loop. Please show the exact data and exact code, not vague descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
if (arduino - > canReadLine()) 
{
    QByteArray serialData = arduino->readLine () ;
    QString serialBuffer = QString :: fromStdString(SerialData.toStdString());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(serialBuffer) ;
}
```

My listWidget displays only a few incoming data, rest is lost.

Comment: That doesn't show your COM params (when you're opening the port). BTW that's not an answer, please add the code to your question and delete your answer.